# Load objects into cache from new thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, caching, .net-3.5

I'm trying to use the [BackgroundWorker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to start a new thread which loads a large number of objects into the cache when the website is started.

My code so far:

```
private void PreLoadCachedSearches()
{
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerReportsProgress = false, WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(WorkerCompleted);
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private static void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Do the cache loading...
    var x = HttpContext.Current.Cache; // BUT the Cache is now null!!!!
}

private static void WorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Logging?
}
```

I put the code in Global.asax.cs and call `PreLoadCachedSearches` during the `Application_Start` event: The new thread is started, but **it fails whenever it tries to access the cache via `HttpContext.Current.Cache` which is null**. I assume HttpContext doesn't exist/isn't available in the new thread I'm kicking off with the BackgroundWorker. 
I've also tried moving the code to a separate page and start the thread manually rather than via the Application_Start event - same problem.
If I call my cache-loading code in the context of the web application (i.e. no threading) it works just fine.

- How do I work around this? Pass in a reference to the cache of the main thread or access it somehow?

This question is a continuation of this previous question, [Asynchronous task in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741543/asynchronous-task-in-asp-net).

Comment: The backgroundworker is intended for WinForms and WPF. It is of no use in an ASP.NET app.

Comment: That's what I thought! But several people have commented it's ok for use in ASP.NET...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have an HttpContext because the thread isn't involved in servicing an Http Request.

Try `HttpRuntime.Cache`

Comment: This is also the way to use the HttpRuntime cache in WinForm applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by passing HttpContex.Current as parameter;

```
private void PreLoadCachedSearches()
{
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerReportsProgress = false, WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(WorkerCompleted);
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(HttpContext.Current);
}

private static void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current = (HttpContext)e.Argument;
    var x = HttpContext.Current.Cache;
}

private static void WorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Logging?
}
```