# ASP.NET WEBAPI MVC service return to page and keep processing asynchronous multthreading?

Tags: multithreading, web-services, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, webmethod

We have a WEBAPI service running on a windows asp.net MVC solution.  There is a load method that takes about 40 minutes to complete and return status on the called page. During that time the browser window is tied up.  What design options do we have if we want the web page to come back with submitted and the process to continue to run and complete.  I don't care if page never shows complete, we can pull that from another status page.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in the past, even though in my case the delay was shorter - 40-50 seconds of loading of fresh data from multiple backend servers in a VPN. It was also in ASP.NET back then, but I believe that the approach is still feasible and you can get some ideas if I share my experience. I remember an old [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741543/asynchronous-task-in-asp-net) that I had favourited in the past and used the insight from it. You can check it out.

Here are some tips, but in short, because I don't remember the details anymore (excuse my google-assisted memory!):

- You should start the task in a new thread and not wait for it in your main thread.
- You should also make sure that the task is started only once and cannot be initiated infinite number of times by the user via refresh or via the UI. So, you better persist the state in the database, so at refresh, the new thread is created only if the database says that it has not been executed recently or it is not in progress.
- Your page will be loaded and show its contents and you can display a .gif representing a progress bar, a loading wheel or something similar to the user.
- The task you started will continue on the server. When it completes you can push and update the UI via ajax from within the code-behind to make the experience even smoother if you like.
- On subsequent requests, you can just retrieve the state of your task from the database in order to display something like `update completed at hh:mm:ss`.

Hope this helps you and I wish you the best of luck!